# Is a good idea to set "leastconn" as load balancing method in HAproxy to handle BOSH connections?

Tags: xmpp, load-balancing, haproxy, basichttpbinding

I have an HAproxy instance used as load balancer of BOSH (http-bind, http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) servers. It was running with "roundrobin" load balancing method, but I experimented some issues, when some instances go down, all the connections are redistributed to the active instances. When the death nodes come up again, they don't have the same amount of connections that the other instances, and they aren't using the same resources. If other instances go down, the sessions will be redistributed again and some servers will be overloaded and some other that are running in their limits go down, so all the service is interrupted, and I need to restart all instances at the same time in order try that the the sessions could be evenly redistributed.

I was reading about how can I configure a BOSH load balancing using HAproxy and I found this book: "Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery". In this book the author recommends that we [can use "leastconn" as balance method for Haproxy](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=rVV_pCb-zzsC&pg=PT380&lpg=PT380&dq=haproxy%20%2b%20bosh&source=bl&ots=_7tVucdm2C&sig=EFR5GRjvt53CGFAoYgO6YMxZ4a4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hRBvUJP6LYHs8gSe-YCoCQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg).

The HAproxy documentation says that we shouldn't use "leastconn" with HTTP connections, but it says that we should use it where very long sessions are expected.

I think that this balancing method can help with the issue when the servers go down, because it will redistribute the sessions equally in the active nodes, and when the instance is up again, all the new sessions will go to this instance until it has the same amount of sessions that the other servers.

Has anyone some experience in this kind of configuration? What HApoxy settings or tuning  do you recommend me in order to balance BOSH connections?

Answer (score 2):

If your sessions are long, and they may be when I read SMPP, then leastconn will provide a better load-balancing than roundrobin.
Roundrobin works well for very short connections.

cheers